# If a function contains a closed point on a graph that ends continuity, is that closed point a one sided limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

If a graph contains the point (-2,-1) and continues right from that point, but left from another point, is -1 a limit of f(x) x->-2^+? [Graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1BWs.png)

I'm learning limits right now and im not sure if a point that is included in a graph is considered a limit, or if a limit is limited to open dots, or points that the function will approach but never reach.

Answer (score 0):

The solid dot just means that point is part of the graph. So if the solid dot is at $(x_0,y_0)$, then $y_0=f(x_0)$ if this is the graph of $f$.

The solidness of the dot does **not** mean it is the limiting value from one side or the other. **That** is determined by whether or not the dot is at the correct location to be the endpoint of the arc of the graph lying on that side.

Answer (score 0):

**Limits existance and graph**

> $\text{When you are calculating limits you should be aware of this:}$
> $\text{In order the limit to exist we have to take into account these conditions:}$
> $\displaystyle \lim_{x^+\to x_0}=\lim_{x^-\to x_0} \text{where $x_0$ its the spot that we are searching for the limit.}$
> $\text{If:} \lim_{x^+\to x_0}\neq \lim_{x^-\to x_0} \text{then} \lim_{x \to x_0} \text{does not exist}$

---

**Is the dot part of the graph?**

> As it was mentioned previously the solid dot means that the point is part of the graph.Moreover,if you want to combine it with limits:
> $\displaystyle \text{Suppose we search limit at x=c then: } \lim_{x\to c}=g \text{ and } f(c)=g$